# Writing intermediate results of spark job on driver with yarn-client mode active

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a flatmap function in spark, that contains a number of python functions.
I am trying to write the output of one of these python functions as a .txt file, locally.

I face the issue that when the application is ran in yarn-client, I can not determine where the .txt file will be written down locally, as it can be in any of the executors.

If I change to local mode, then I can get the .txt file written on the driver machine, but the process is very slow.

I am unsure if I can make use of the collect() function, since that would run on the results of the flatmap function, and these are not the results I am looking for.

Is there a way too run the application in yarn-client mode, and have the output of that specific function written on the driver machine?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do it fast, any way you have to transfer data to the driver  before writing. So why you bother with local files? If you have YARN, you should have HDFS - just use it.

Comment: Also if you really do want to write files on the local file system in yarn-client use "file:///path/to/directory/"

Comment: Thanks. It was needed ti have the files written locally. Finally I filtered to a smaller amount of data and ran the application in local mode.